My VBscript program to repeatedly press the enter key is not working
I need the program to press enter a specified number of times defined by "counter" in the loop. The problem is, when it is supposed to focus on google chrome (I have a .html file that requires the enter key be pressed), it opens way too many tabs of the html file.
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.shell")
objShell.AppActivate("chrome.exe")
Dim counter
counter = 1
Do While counter <=9
    wscript.sleep 1000
    ws.sendkeys "{ENTER}"
    wscript.sleep 1
    counter = counter + 1
Loop

Please help me fix this. I am new to vbscript and I had just compiled this program based on different online forums.
When ran, the program opens too many tabs even though I didn't specify for it to do so. I just need a simple program to press the enter key on a chrome page. Thanks!

This may be helpful
